# Flavor based gradle dependency version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I have an app with a good number of flavors: `flava1`, `flava2`, `flava3`..... (and the number of flavors keep increasing as time goes by).

The app uses a dependency `some-lib` of version `X.X.X`. But *one* of the flavors, say, `flava2` requires that dependency to be of version `X.X.Y` while the other flavors continue with `X.X.X`.

I tried using the flavor based dependency line like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.example:some-lib:X.X.X'
  flava2Implementation 'com.example:some-lib:X.X.Y'
}
```

but it would always end up using `X.X.X`. I even tried changing the order of those 2 lines (placing `flava2Implementation` first) but that didn't work either.

Is there any other way to accomplish this without having to explicitly write `flava1Implmentation`, `flava3Implmentation`, `flava4Implmentation` etc etc for all flavors other than `flava2`? Because every time a new flavor gets added, we might forget to add a line in the dependencies for it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this with `dimensions`:

```
flavorDimensions "flav1", "other"
productFlavors {
    flav1 {
        dimension "flav1"
        applicationIdSuffix ".flav1"
    }
    flav2 {
        dimension "other"
        applicationIdSuffix ".flav2"
    }
    flav3 {
        dimension "other"
        applicationIdSuffix ".flav3"
    }

    forOther {
        dimension "other"
    }

}
```

Then we can add implementation only for `forOther`

```
 implementation 'com.example:some-lib:X.X.X'
flav1Implementation 'com.example:some-lib:X.X.Y'

forOtherImplementation 'com.example:some-lib:Z.Z.Z'
```

Because `forOther/
       <included in flav2/flav3>`